# How to run a section of code in Python, similar to Matlab

Tags: python, matlab, python-idle

I have a code which consists of 1) loading data, and 2) doing things with the data.

```
# Load data
import geoio.vtio as vtio
(traces, params)=vtio.vt_read("../Seismic/R2771_10PRDMkf_Full_T_Rzn_RMO.vt")

# Do things with the data
N=params['num_samples']
dt=params['digi']
```

Usually when I run a Python script I simply hit "F5" in IDLE and it doesn't take too long to re-run any previous computations. In this case, however, the loading of the data takes several seconds, and I would like to run the additional commands only, similar to running a section of code in an m-file in Matlab. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really talk about `iPython`

## Learning iPython goodies

Use `?` to get started

```
>>> ?
IPython -- An enhanced Interactive Python
=========================================

IPython offers a combination of convenient shell features, special commands
and a history mechanism for both input (command history) and output (results
caching, similar to Mathematica). It is intended to be a fully compatible
replacement for the standard Python interpreter, while offering vastly
improved functionality and flexibility.

At your system command line, type 'ipython -h' to see the command line
options available. This document only describes interactive features.

MAIN FEATURES
-------------

* Access to the standard Python help. As of Python 2.1, a help system is
  available with access to object docstrings and the Python manuals. Simply
  type 'help' (no quotes) to access it.

* Magic commands: type %magic for information on the magic subsystem.

* System command aliases, via the %alias command or the configuration file(s).

* Dynamic object information:

  Typing ?word or word? prints detailed information about an object.  If
  certain strings in the object are too long (docstrings, code, etc.) they get
  snipped in the center for brevity.

  Typing ??word or word?? gives access to the full information without
  snipping long strings. Long strings are sent to the screen through the less
  pager if longer than the screen, printed otherwise.
  ....etc....
```

### Learn `%magic`

```
>>> %magic    
IPython's 'magic' functions
===========================

The magic function system provides a series of functions which allow you to
control the behavior of IPython itself, plus a lot of system-type
features. There are two kinds of magics, line-oriented and cell-oriented.

Line magics are prefixed with the % character and work much like OS
command-line calls: they get as an argument the rest of the line, where
arguments are passed without parentheses or quotes.  For example, this will
time the given statement::

        %timeit range(1000)

Cell magics are prefixed with a double %%, and they are functions that get as
an argument not only the rest of the line, but also the lines below it in a
separate argument.  These magics are called with two arguments: the rest of the
call line and the body of the cell, consisting of the lines below the first.
For example::

        %%timeit x = numpy.random.randn((100, 100))
        numpy.linalg.svd(x)

will time the execution of the numpy svd routine, running the assignment of x
as part of the setup phase, which is not timed.
...etc...
```

## My favourites

- %edit - edit something (previous lines, function, my file) in external editor
- %load - load data from a file and, let you add some text, then run it
- %debug - debug crashed script
- %history - show what you have done so far
- %paste - paste and run code from a clipboard
- %macro - this might be solution to your question
- %timeit - measure execution time
- %recall - also close to your question
- %rerun - try it too

In general, I am always finding some productivity booster in iPython if I walk through its help. Try it too.

Note: I am using iPyhton from console, but other UI versions shall provide very similar, if not exactly the same functionality.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Jan, but I stated the wrong environment: I'm working in IDLE, not iPython. (My apologies).