# How to run a "section" of a python script, like Matlab

Tags: python, vim, ide

When using vim (or any other text editor) for python scripts, is there a way to run a section of your script alone?

Matlab has a feature where beginning a line with `%%` splits the lines of code that follow into a section of its own, that can be run independently. Is there a way of achieving this without having to use iPython? Even if the solution is a bit hacky, it would be an improvement over what I currently am doing, which is commenting out blocks that I don't want to run.

Comment: here you can find a detailed answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40289706/execute-selection-from-script-in-vim/40290101

Comment: Visit https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23550853/how-to-run-a-section-of-code-in-python-similar-to-matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generic solution would be vim-slime: https://github.com/jpalardy/vim-slime

> SLIME is an Emacs plugin to turn Emacs into a Lisp IDE. You can type
> text in a file, send it to a live REPL, and avoid having to reload all
> your code every time you make a change.
>
> Vim-slime is a humble attempt at getting *some* of these features into
> Vim. It works with any REPL and isn't tied to Lisp.